# Merging two datasets with same dimensions?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, merge, finance

Based on stock data I've created two dataframes for stocks I want to buy (Winner) and short (Loser). This means that values in both dataframes that aren't "Winner" or "Loser" takes on the value "False".

```
WinLos_df = creturns_df.copy()
WinLos_df = WinLos_df.apply(lambda x: (x >= creturns_df['upper bound']))
WinLos2_df = creturns_df.copy()
WinLos2_df = WinLos2_df.apply(lambda x: (x <= creturns_df['lower bound']))
WinLos_df[WinLos_df == True] = 'Winner'
WinLos2_df[WinLos2_df == True] = 'Loser'
print(WinLos_df.tail())
print(WinLos2_df.tail())
```

Here's a snippet of each of the two datasets:

Loser :

```
                    MMM    ABT   ABBV   ABMD    ACN   ATVI   ADBE    AMD  \
31-10-2019 00:00  Loser  False  Loser  Loser  False  False  False  False   
29-11-2019 00:00  Loser  False  False  Loser  False  False  Loser  False   
31-12-2019 00:00  False  False  False  Loser  False  False  False  False   
31-01-2020 00:00  Loser  False  False  Loser  False  False  False  False   
21-02-2020 00:00  Loser  False  False  Loser  False  False  False  False
```

Winner :

```
                   MMM    ABT    ABBV   ABMD    ACN    ATVI    ADBE     AMD  \
31-10-2019 00:00  False  False   False  False  False  Winner   False   False   
29-11-2019 00:00  False  False   False  False  False  Winner   False  Winner   
31-12-2019 00:00  False  False   False  False  False  Winner   False  Winner   
31-01-2020 00:00  False  False  Winner  False  False  Winner   False  Winner   
21-02-2020 00:00  False  False  Winner  False  False  Winner  Winner  Winner
```

Now I want to join or merge these two dataframes, so that I get one dataframe, with the values "Winner" , "Loser" and "False".
There's no observations that takes on both values "Winner" and "Loser".

Is there any smart way to combine these two?
I hope my question is understandable, and that I've provided enough code.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want to concatenate the datasets vertically?

Comment: If fairly new to python, so if you by concentrating mean that there should be added additional rows, then that was not my intention. The rows and columns should stay the same, but the values should be something like :  If WinLos_df.value == WinLos2_df.value : Return 'False'     Elif WinLos_df.value == 'Winner' :   Return "Winner"   Elif WinLos2_df.value == 'Loser' :  Return 'Loser'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inherent values of the dfs to do as requested

```
WinLos = WinLos_df.values
WinLos2 = WinLos2_df.values
n,m = WinLos_df.shape

merged = np.empty(shape=(n,m), dtype=object)

for i in range(n):
  for j in range(m):
      merged[i,j] = False
      if WinLos[i,j]:
        merged[i,j] = 'Winner'
      if WinLos2[i,j]:
        merged[i,j] = 'Looser'
```

and then potentially transfer the merged array into a dataframe